# unable to install youtube-dl

Tags: apt, software-installation, youtube-dl

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  youtube-dl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 237 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe youtube-dl all 2014.02.17-1 [237 kB]
Fetched 5,080 B in 3s (1,450 B/s)                       
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/youtube-dl/youtube-dl_2014.02.17-1_all.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Try the suggested method: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`

Answer (score 2):

The package is likely outdated so useless. You should just install manually & update every couple of weeks or if it breaks.

Instructions here - https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Most common method -

`sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2016.05.10/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

`sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

To update   `sudo youtube-dl -U`

Answer (score 1):

The `youtube-dl` version in the default repositories is outdated. To install the more current one - open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Additionally (as @Ron mentioned in his comment under your question), to fix the errors execute :

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```